# Problems on the keyboard, some missing options

Tags: release-loki, keyboard

Some keyboard options not displayed.

This options are missing on the keyboard settings of Loki:

```
Character Maps, Text Entry Settings and Keyboard Layout Chart.
```

In the Freya had these options.

The shortcuts that matches the screenshot don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Download tweak tool from the app centre. It covers the cmd/ctrl switch and lets you assign € to shift+4 instead of $.

looking for the umlaut options still...

Answer (score 0):

I agree, keyboard options are very poor to date. Ideally I need the following:

1. remap the cmd and ctrl keys on my apple keyboard - I use both systems often and it's a pain to try to remember which is which. I want to flip them in eOS so ctrl is cmd and vice versa.
2. I'm an English speaker living in Europe, and so need access to special characters like ö, ü, ä, accents and the € symbol. The compose+shift+"+letter works well enough but really slows down typing in German. The apple system of opt+u+letter for umlaut and so on is quite elegant and I'd like to use that if it's possible.